# Delete column from content type doesn't work

Tags: list, powershell, column, delete

This is the code I use:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$web = Get-SPWeb "Myshareointsite/Projects/Test"
$list = $web.Lists["Risks"]
$ContentType = $list.ContentTypes["Item"]
$ColumnName = "Comment"
    if($ContentType -ne $null)
    {
 Write-host $ContentType.Fields
        if($ContentType.Fields.ContainsField($ColumnName))
        {

        $ContentType.FieldLinks.Delete($ColumnName)
        $ContentType.Update()
        Write-Host "Field removed from the Content Type!" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Host "Field Doesn't Exists in the Content Type!" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host "Content type not found!" -ForegroundColor Red 
    }
```

at the end of the execution, I get the message: 
Field removed from the content type but when I check in the column, the field is still there
any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using your code in below format:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  
#Variables
$SiteURL="http://intranet.crescent.com/"
$ListName="Change Request"
$ColumnName="Activity Status"
 
#Get Internal Name of the columns
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
 
#Get the list
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)
 
if($List -ne $null)
{
    #Get the column
    $column = $list.Fields[$ColumnName]
 
    if($column -ne $null)
    {
        #Reset column properties to allow delete
        $column.Hidden = $false
        $column.ReadOnlyField = $false
        $column.AllowDeletion = $true
        $column.Update()
 
        #Delete the column from list
        $list.Fields.Delete($column)
        write-host "Column has been deleted!" -f Green
    }
    else
     {
        write-host "Specified column name not found!" -ForegroundColor Red
     }
}
```

**References**:

1. [How to Remove a Column from SharePoint List using PowerShell?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/04/how-to-remove-column-from-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html)
2. [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)